# How can I get sinon to yield to multiple callbacks

Tags: javascript, ajax, sinon

I am trying to stub several ajax calls, but I want to have both beforeSend and success executed, is this possible?

I want something like this:

```
var stub = sinon.stub(jQuery, "ajax");
stub.onCall(0).yieldsTo("beforeSend").yieldsTo("success", {some: 'data'});
stub.onCall(1).yieldsTo("beforeSend").yieldsTo("success", {other: 'stuff'});
```

But this skips the 'beforeSend' method.

I know it would be easier to allow ajax to do it's stuff and use sinon's fakeServer, but I can't as I'm testing in Node with a fake browser and it just [doesn't work](https://github.com/cjohansen/Sinon.JS/issues/319)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to work around this by adding some additional code:

```
var responses = {};
var executionComplete;

beforeEach(function () {
    executionComplete = $.Deferred();
    sinon.stub($, "ajax", function (options) {
        if (options.beforeSend) {
            options.beforeSend();
        }
        completeAjaxCall(options);
    });
});

afterEach(function () {
    $.ajax.restore();
});

var completeAjaxCall = function (options) {
    var response = findResponse(options.url, options.type);
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (response.code < 400) {
            if (options.dataFilter && response.data) {
                response.data = options.dataFilter(JSON.stringify(response.data));
            }
            if (options.success) {
                options.success(response.data);
            }
        } else {
            if (options.error) {
                options.error(response.data);
            }
        }
        if (options.complete) {
            options.complete();
        }
        if (response.completeExecution) {
            executionComplete.resolve();
        }
    }, response.serverResponseTime);
};

var findResponse = function (url, type) {
    var response = responses[url];
    expect(response, url + ' should have a response').to.exist;
    expect(response.type).to.equal(type);
    delete responses[url];
    if (Object.keys(responses).length === 0) {
        response.completeExecution = true;
    }
    return response;
};

var givenResponse = function (response) {
    responses[response.url] = response;
};
```

Then in my test I can use it like this:

```
it('should do some stuff', function (done) {
    //given
    givenResponse({serverResponseTime: 4, code: 200, url: '/saveStuff', type: 'POST'});
    givenResponse({serverResponseTime: 1, code: 200, url: '/getStuff', type: 'GET'});

    //when
    $('button').click();

    //then
    executionComplete.then(function () {
        expect(something).to.be.true;
        done();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `yieldTo` after the call:

```
var stub = sinon.stub();
stub({
    foo: function() {
        console.log('foo');
    },
    bar: function() {
        console.log('bar');
    }
});
stub.yieldTo('foo');
stub.yieldTo('bar');
```

Comment: Yes, but that would yield to 'foo' and 'bar' that were set up in the test. I want to yield to functions in the method that is being stubbed.